# Why is a variable not getting assigned to when assignments exist in both clauses of an if-else block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, iterator, iteration

Suppose we have something like:

```
if True:
    r = 0
else:
    r = 1
print(r)
```

Why would we get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment`?

The actual code is shown below:

```
def rasterize_dot_verify_args(callable, parent):

    if not hasattr(callable, "__call__"):
        raise ValueError()
    import inspect
    siggy = inspect.signature(callable)
    if (len(siggy.parameters) > 1):
        raise ValueError()

def rasterize(callable, xparent, make_copy :bool = False):
    rasterize_dot_verify_args(callable, xparent)

    iparent = xparent
    if make_copy:
        import copy
        iparent = copy.deepcopy(xparent)

    if hasattr(iparent, "__iter__"):
        in_kids = iter(iparent)
        if in_kids != iparent:
            lamby = lambda p, *, c=callable: rasterize(c, p)
            out_kids = map(lamby, in_kids)

            # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            r = callable(out_kids)  # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    else:
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        r = iparent  # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    return r

import itertools as itts
sixify = lambda obj, *, itts=itts: itts.repeat(obj, 6)
inputs = map(sixify, range(1, 5))

# inputs = (_ for _ in [
#      itts.repeat(1, 6),
#      itts.repeat(2, 6),
#      itts.repeat(3, 6),
#      itts.repeat(4, 6)
# ])

print(rasterize(list, inputs))
```

I'm forced to add a little bit of text here because, "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

oh dear.... even more text is needed.

Comment: `r = callable(out_kids)` is not only in an `if`, there's an inner `if` as well that might evaluate to false

Answer (score 1):

`r` would not be assigned when `hasattr(iparent, "__iter__")` is `True` and `in_kids` != `iparent` is `False`. You should add an `else` block to the `if in_kids != iparent:` statement to assign `r` a value.

Answer (score 1):

A better characterization of your code would be:

```
if test1:
    if test2:
        r = something
else:
    r = something
```

Which should make it obvious how you'd get the error you got.